# $-\Delta u>0$ if and only if $u>0$ in this pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\Omega$ a smooth domain with $|\Omega|<\infty$. I am studying this problem
\begin{cases}
      \Delta^2u=|u|^{p-1}u\mbox{ in }\Omega,\\
      u=\Delta u=0\mbox{ on }\partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
I would like to check that $-\Delta u>0$ if and only if $u>0$ (In $\Omega$). But I could not and I do not know any result to help me. Is there any property about $\Delta^2u>0$?

Comment: $\Delta u:=\sum \partial^2u/\partial x_i^2$.